# Importing Bootstrap to project pages via CDN

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap on my simple project, and I can import it on my `index.html` successfully. I also need bootstrap on other pages of my projects such as `about.html` Do I need to add the Bootstrap CDN on the header of that page as well?

Comment: Yes.  If you have code that you want to add to many pages, you may want to make a file `commoncode.php` and put this on every page: `<?php include "commoncode.php" ?>`.  That's like a `#include` from C: it basically copy pastes the code there.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use bootstrap on my simple project, and I can import it on my index.html successfully

You can add the below code within `<head>...</head>`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

> I also need bootstrap on other pages of my projects such as about.html Do I need to add the Bootstrap CDN on the header of that page as well?

If each page is a static `.html` file (with no routing), you will need to add the Bootstrap stylesheet to each one.

You may also want to look at the [introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) on the Bootstrap website as they provide a boilerplate to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 projects, it is easier to work with the Bootstrap framework than with other libraries, basically it would be enough to copy the respective classes of the component, insert it in the index and use it for the entire project: `<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`